# process returned 3, terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

const int MAX=1e6+1;
string d[MAX]={0};

int stn(char c)
{
    return c-'0';
}

char nts(int n)
{
    return(char)(n+48);
}

void st(string a, string b)
{
    int l1=a.size(), l2=b.size();
    if (l1>=l2)
    {
        b.insert(0,l1-l2,'0');
    }
    else
    {
        a.insert(0,l2-l1,'0');
    }
}
string sum(string a, string b)
{
    string s="";
    st(a,b);
    int l=a.length();

    int tmp=0;
    for (int i=l-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        tmp=stn(a[i])+stn(b[i]) +tmp;
        s.insert(0,1,nts(tmp%10));
        tmp=tmp/10;
    }
    if (tmp>0)
    {
        s.insert(0,1,nts(tmp));
    }
    return s;
}
int main()
{
    freopen("stairs.inp", "r", stdin);
    freopen("stairs.out", "w", stdout);
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(0); cout.tie(0);

    string n; cin >> n;
    int nmax=n.size();
    n='0'+n;

    d[0]="1";
    for (int i=1; i<=nmax; ++i)
    {
        if (n[i]=='0') d[i]="0";
        else
        {
            d[i]=d[i-1];
            if (i>=2) d[i]=sum(d[i], d[i-2]);
            if (i>=3) d[i]=sum(d[i], d[i-3]);
        }
    }
    cout << d[nmax];
    return 0;
}
```

I was trying to do my homework given by my teacher, but somehow I got this error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
>   what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid

I have no idea what the problem is. Is it because of the memory range or the string or something?

Comment: It is clear from the error message that you are constructing a `std::string` object from a null `char*`. That is *undefined behavior*. Your library's implementation chooses to throw an `std::logic_error` exception. You need to step through your code with a debugger and find the faulty construction.

Comment: Towards the bottom of the [ask] page is a link that you might find helpful: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).